# .net core EF FirstOrDefaultAsync can not get data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I meet a strange question. I use `.net core 3.1`, pkg is `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`, DB is `Sqlite`.

My Entity:

```cs
public class Company
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Introduction { get; set; }
}
```

Handler interface:

```cs
public interface ICompanyRepository
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Company>> GetCompaniesAsync();
    Task<Company> GetCompanyAsync(Guid companyId);
    Task<bool> CompanyExistsAsync(Guid companyId);
}
```

When I implement the following method, only first one `GetCompaniesAsync` return data, others return null:

```cs
// This method can be return data
public async Task<IEnumerable<Company>> GetCompaniesAsync()
{
    return await _context.Companies.ToListAsync();
}

// This method return null
public async Task<Company> GetCompanyAsync(Guid companyId)
{
    if (companyId == Guid.Empty)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(companyId));
    }

    return await _context.Companies.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == companyId);
}

// This method also return null
public async Task<bool> CompanyExistsAsync(Guid companyId)
{
    if (companyId == Guid.Empty)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(companyId));
    }

    return await _context.Companies.AnyAsync(x => x.Id == companyId);
}
```

I tried to remove the `await`:

```cs
public async Task<Company> GetCompanyAsync(Guid companyId)
{
    if (companyId == Guid.Empty)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(companyId));
    }

    foreach (var c in _context.Companies.ToList())
    {
        if (c.Id == companyId)
        {
            return c;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

It can return normal data instead of `null`.

The following is the method called in the controller:

```cs
public async Task<Company> GetCompany(Guid companyId)
{
    var company = await companyRepository.GetCompanyAsync(companyId);
    if (company == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(company);
}
```

In head, I have `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Also, I've seen people say that installing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` is fine, but I still can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, Guid must be uppercase in the database to match.